# setting up routing for the first time

Tags: routes, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to set up url routing on my server for the first time.  I'm fairly sure that mod_rewrite is enabled.  Are there any other configurations I need to change or things to set up?  Should the routing.yml file just automatically get read?

Answer (score 1):

routing.yml is unrelated to Apache. Assuming you have Apache pointing at the appropriate directory and at the proper index, Symfony should handle the rest.